# Why does my catch() handle the error event?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, async-await

Can someone explain why my `catch()` doesn't work? I get

```
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^
```

from this

```
const https = require('https');

const options = {
  hostname: 'github.comx',
  port: 443,
  path: '/',
  method: 'GET'
};

async function main() {
  options.agent = new https.Agent(options);
  const valid_to = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      const req = https.request({
        ...options, checkServerIdentity: function (host, cert) {
          resolve(cert.valid_to);
        }
      });
      req.end();
    } catch (error) {
      reject(error);
    };
  });
  return valid_to;
};

(async () => {
  let a = await main();
  console.log(a);
  a = await main();
  console.log(a);
})();
```

**Update**

Here I try withiy try/catch, but get

```
TypeError: https.request(...).then is not a function
```

error.

```
async function main() {
  options.agent = new https.Agent(options);
  const valid_to = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    const req = https.request({
      ...options, checkServerIdentity: function (host, cert) {
        resolve(cert.valid_to);
      }
    }).then(response => {
      req.end();
    }).catch(rej => {
      reject(rej);
    });
  });
  return valid_to;
};
```

**Update 2**

Here the promise is moved inside the try block, but I get same error.

```
async function main() {
  options.agent = new https.Agent(options);
  try {
    const valid_to = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const req = https.request({
        ...options, checkServerIdentity: function (host, cert) {
          resolve(cert.valid_to);
        }
      });
      req.end();
    });
    return valid_to;
  } catch (error) {
    reject(error);
  };
};
```

Comment: I would assume it's because the `https.request` error is happening after the try/catch has been run

Comment: Because the error is thrown asynchronously, but you're trying to catch it synchronously. You'd need to use some error handler callback of `https.request` instead.

Comment: Your promise needs an error handler. If you reject the promise, it will throw the rejection as an error.
You should move your promise within the try catch block or add a .catch((error) => {/*some error handling*/} to your promise.

Comment: @deceze I have not tried with then/catch instead, but then I run into a different problem. Updated OP with new code and error at the bottom. I imagine I am not even close?

Comment: @NickG I have now tried that, and I get the same error. Can you take a look at the OP at the bottom, where I have posted my attempt in "Update 2"?

Comment: Sidenote: you don't need the `const valid_to = await new Promise(); return valid_to`; With async functions, you can simply return the promise.

Comment: @deceze about using try/catch in asynchronously. If I read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await#adding_error_handling then I get the impression, that it is allowed?

Comment: *If* the function you’re calling is *awaitable*, then you can use a synchronous-looking `try..catch`. Apparently your functions isn’t though and uses the older callback-based async approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`request` is a stream, so you should register error listener there, reject, and then catch the error:

```
async function main() {
  options.agent = new https.Agent(options);
  const valid_to = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      const req = https.request({
        ...options, checkServerIdentity: function (host, cert) {
          resolve(cert.valid_to);
        }
      }).on('error', (error) => {
        console.error(error);
        reject(error);
    });
      req.end();

  });
  return valid_to;
};

(async () => {
  let a = await main().catch(err=>console.log(err));
  console.log(a);
})();
```

Comment: So whenever I see `on` and `end`, then I am dealing with a stream?

Comment: @SandraSchlichting yeah, pretty much, it's actually EventEmitter API, check [Events](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events)